# How to get photos using pyTelegramBotAPI?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, py-telegram-bot-api

I am trying to achieve this logic from the Telegram bot (I use the desktop version of the client):

1. The bot asks to send a photo
2. The user sends photos (both with and without grouping)
3. The bot receives all the photos sent by the user
4. Only after receiving all the photos, the bot sends a message about the successful operation and transfers control to the next function.

My code is:

```
import telebot

bot_token = '1279****77:AAHJDPFJ************KJfLbiI'
bot = telebot.TeleBot(bot_token, parse_mode='html')
photo_list = []

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def send_welcome(message):
    send = bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Send your pics...')
    bot.register_next_step_handler(send, get_user_pics)
    return

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['photo'])
def get_user_pics(message):
    if message.photo[-1].file_id not in photo_list:
        photo_list.append(message.photo[-1].file_id)
        if len(photo_list) == 1:
            send = bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Photos received...")
            bot.register_next_step_handler(send, process_messages())
            return

def process_messages():
    print(photo_list)
    return

bot.polling()
```

Now, the logic only works if the user sends photos with grouping.
If sent without grouping (~ 10 photos), then after about the 4th photo, the bot writes that it successfully took the photo and nothing else ...
**So how do I achieve the required logic, regardless of whether the photos are grouped or not?**

Answer (score 0):

Try to do something like this:

```
import telebot

bot_token = '1279****77:AAHJDPFJ************KJfLbiI'
bot = telebot.TeleBot(bot_token, parse_mode='html')
photo_list = []

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def send_welcome(message):
    send = bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Send your pics...')
    bot.register_next_step_handler(send, get_user_pics)
    return

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['photo'])
def get_user_pics(message):
    if message.text == '/done':
        process_messages()
        return
    elif message.photo[-1].file_id not in photo_list:
        photo_list.append(message.photo[-1].file_id)
    send = bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Send another photo or click /done")
    bot.register_next_step_handler(send, get_user_pics)
    return

def process_messages():
    print(photo_list)
    return

bot.polling()
```